# Magento 2 : Display custom field (customer attribute) in "checkout register" form

Tags: magento2, module, checkout, attributes, customer

I want to add new field (customer custom attribute) to the checkout register form.

Items already created:

- Customer attribute
- Source model for customer attribute
- Display field in `adminhtml customer` form
- Display field in `customer account create` form
- Display field in `customer account edit` form

**Now I need to Display this field as selection (from source model) in "checkout register" form**

Could anyone help me !!

Comment: Not a duplicated question .. i've already added the attribute so i want to display it in checkout_register form (not in customer_account_create or other forms ..)

Comment: this is magento 2 question , how magento 2 duplicate magento 1

Comment: this link will help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/254856/magento-2-how-to-add-custom-attribute-to-customer-address-and-how-to-insert-valu
just uncomment the "used_in_forms" lines