# Magento 2 How to add custom attribute to customer address and how to insert value in that attribute?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer, eav, address

I want to add a new custom attribute to "customer_address" that I did with an attribute installer script, now I am able to see that field in "eav_attribute" table. I have created a module and I have one observer for "custmer_save_after" in that. Now I want to set a custom value for that custom attribute which I created from the script.

how can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have created it with below code in InstallData.php file.

```
namespace Module\Name\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $customerAddressEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer_address');
        $attributeSetId = $customerAddressEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'location_id', [
            'type'          => 'int',
            'label'         => 'Location Id',
            'input'         => 'text',
            'required'      =>  false,
            'visible'       =>  true,
            'user_defined'  =>  true,
            'sort_order'    =>  13,
            'position'      =>  13,
            'system'        =>  0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'location_id')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId
            ]);

        $attribute->save();        
    }
}
```

then run the below commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f (optional in `develop` mode) 
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: I have one issue is, now the "location_id" is showing in each address. How can i remove it?

Comment: I got the issue, I have "'visible'  =>  true," in addAttribute. we need to set it as FALSE.

Comment: This looks good, but for some reaspon it is not working on my magento 2.3.3 CE, there is no error, the setup ends as expected, but the attribute is not present in the DB

Answer (score 0):

**------- CREATE CUSTOMER ADDRESS ATTRIBUTE --------**

**Step 1** : create app/code/Dckap/CustomerAddressAttribute

**Step 2** : Create app/code/Dckap/CustomerAddressAttribute/etc/module.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Dckap_CustomerAddressAttribute" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step 3** : Create app/code/Dckap/CustomerAddressAttribute/registration.php

```
 <?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Dckap_CustomerAddressAttribute',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step 4** : Create app/code/Dckap/CustomerAddressAttribute/Setup/InstallData.php

```
   <?php

namespace Dckap\CustomerAddressAttribute\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0') < 0){

                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $customerSetup = $objectManager->create('Dckap\CustomerAddressAttribute\Setup\CustomerSetup');
                $customerSetup->installAttributes($customerSetup);



        }

    }
}
```

**Step 5** : Create app/code/Dckap/CustomerAddressAttribute/Setup/CustomerSetup.php

```
 <?php

namespace Dckap\CustomerAddressAttribute\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Setup\Context;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\CollectionFactory;

class CustomerSetup extends EavSetup {

    protected $eavConfig;

    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        Context $context,
        CacheInterface $cache,
        CollectionFactory $attrGroupCollectionFactory,
        Config $eavConfig
        ) {
        $this -> eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        parent :: __construct($setup, $context, $cache, $attrGroupCollectionFactory);
    } 

    public function installAttributes($customerSetup) {
        $this -> installCustomerAttributes($customerSetup);
        $this -> installCustomerAddressAttributes($customerSetup);
    } 

    public function installCustomerAttributes($customerSetup) {

    } 

    public function installCustomerAddressAttributes($customerSetup) {


        $customerSetup -> addAttribute('customer_address',
            'custom_address_attribute',
            [
            'label' => 'Customer Address Attribute',
            'system' => 0,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'position' => 100,
            'sort_order' =>100,
            'visible' =>  true,
            'default_value' => '',
            'note' => '',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'input' => 'text',

            ]
            );

        $customerSetup -> getEavConfig() -> getAttribute('customer_address', 'custom_address_attribute')->setData('is_user_defined',1)->setData('default_value','')-> setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_register_address', 'customer_address_edit']) -> save();


    } 

    public function getEavConfig() {
        return $this -> eavConfig;
    } 
}
```

**Finaly run command**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but i already added attribute to customer_address. now i want to set custom value for that attribute. please help for that.

Comment: I have created "location_id" attribute using the same code, now that 'location_id' is showing in checkout address. I don't want to show it anywhere.
I used in the code:

'used_in_forms' => [
                  //'adminhtml_customer_address',
                  //'customer_address_edit',
                  //'customer_register_address'
                ],

is there something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to my this module https://github.com/rashigoyal14/main/blob/master/Createaccount.zip

All coded there

Thanks
Rashi